# Regex password must contain letters , at least one special character and at least one numeric?

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I am working on password validation , I am supposed to validate the password as such, it always accept the password only if it contains letters, at least one special character and at least one numeric value.

Can anyone help me with the script for this.

Comment: You probably want to check the length too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myPass.match(/\d/) && myPass.match(/[a-zA-Z]/) && myPass.match(/\W/))
//you're good to go
```

//edit
the first test sees if there are any digits, the second looks for any and all alphabet characters and the third looks for "non Word" characters. That describes the three classes that you specified. If you wanted to test for a minimum number of chars you would add one more test which would be

```
&& myPass.length > minimumLength
```

Comment: The question said "letters" were required, but `\w` will match digits and underscores (as well as letters)...

Comment: @manishearth, I think it's so obvious that it really doesn't need any explanation, but *just to make you happy... I've edited :)

Comment: +2 code only answers are discouraged. You need to help others learn, and make the Internet  better. Motto of SE, I think. Anyway, good explanation. Try to remember this next time, you'll then be one of the select few on SO writing good posts :p

Comment: @Manishearth (not that I'd encourage you to take the time but...) if you look through my previous answers I really do try to be very clear about what I'm saying, unless I feel that the OP has a firm grasp of the subject matter and is just looking for a nudge, as was the case with this one. but you're right, it never hurts to be extra clear.

Comment: Saw a few, not all perfect, but none of em deserve a downvote(of the ones ive seen). I may upvote them later, I reached my vote limit already.